# QEMU gdb server thread problem

Tags: ida, gdb, arm, qemu

I am having a problem using a statically compiled QEMU arm version. I am trying to debug an application from an embedded device. Everything seems to work fine except breakpoints on other threads. I am using IDAs remote gdb function to debug. Instead of breaking here [image]

it gives me a SIGTRAP and goes to here [image]
Using hardware breakpoints also doesn't do the trick.

**Edit:** The problem doesn't seem to be IDA itself.
I was using qemu-arm-static version 2.0.0. IDA seems to have the bug I mentioned above. Using commandline gdb-multiarch to try and debug it I get the following error after hitting the breakpoint:

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0xf67c523c in ?? ()
(gdb) info registers
/build/buildd/gdb-7.7.1/gdb/findvar.c:292: internal-error: value_of_register_lazy: Assertion `frame_id_p (get_frame_id (frame))' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n) y

/build/buildd/gdb-7.7.1/gdb/findvar.c:292: internal-error: value_of_register_lazy: Assertion `frame_id_p (get_frame_id (frame))' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
```

This happens with the 2.0.0 qemu version as well as the 2.8.0 version I got from [here](https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static/releases/)

Comment: This may be an IDA related issue. Please consider crossposting to their support channels as well.

Comment: @Nordwald Do you mean contacting their support?

Comment: @Nordwald I think this isn't an IDA related issue. It is either a QEMU issue or a gdb issue. I have edited my question above.

Comment: In that case, is any of these reports related? https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17700 https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17379

Comment: @Nordwald the first one might be related since the web server probably handles the requests in a new thread. My application also is a webserver but also not really. It doesn't get files from the filesystem it just creates some defined responses

Answer (score 3):

QEMU user-mode emulation (e.g. `qemu-arm`, `qemu-arm-static`) does not support debugging multiple threads simultaneously.

You must use `qemu-arm-system` and run an entire ARM kernel.

Separately, your QEMU and GDB are very out-of-date.  I recommend updating:

- QEMU / `qemu-static`.  The latest version is `2.10.1`.  QEMU 2.0.0 is over three years old.
- `gdb` / `gdb-multiarch` / `gdbserver`.  The latest version is `8.0.1`.  GDB 7.7 is over three years old.

Finally, if you do not need to debug multiple threads simultaneously, you can attach to the "appropriate" thread by using

- `set detach-on-fork off`
- `set follow-fork-mode [parent|child]` as appropriate